# DotNetCore project - add Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions

Tags: asp.net-core, nuget

I have some sample code which uses INodeServices that has been obsolete. The recommendation is to use Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions. I have added Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices NuGet package to the project but there is no Extensions in that package. Any idea what else am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: According to microsoft you should use "Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions" but there is no documentation for now. Also I think they may not support NodeServices. You should check this. https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore/issues/12890#issuecomment-518808555

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions,
Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices don't include Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions:
[image]

Comment: My problem is that I am trying to adapt the code that uses  INodeServices. So, essentially, what extension should I add?